# ::selection for IOS

Tags: ios, css, selection

On a new website we want that when the user clicks on the input field, the text gets selected. I'm using ::selection for this, see: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/s/selection/ This works fine for all browsers and android, but not for IOS.

The code looks like this:

```
#div-01::selection { 
    background-color: transparent; 
    color: rgb(251,251,251); 
    text-shadow: none; 
}
```

Is there a way to get this working for IOS? If you have any other option to get this working let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Try removing `#div-01` from the selector

Comment: I've already tried it, doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: In 2024, Safari for iOS [**still doesn’t support `::selection`**](https://caniuse.com/css-selection). Overall, Safari for iOS is like the new Internet Explorer for developers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari for iOS is currently not supporting `::selection` in any way. So no, you can't use it on iOS.

Comment: Ok thanks @KittMedia. Do you have any idea if there is a workaround to get something similar to this for IOS?

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to hide the selection highlight in a text input, and using `background-color: transparent;` in a `::selection` for a text input failed only iOS browsers. My use case involved programmatically controlling what was selected. By combining the programmatic selection and [turning off user selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9314458/8227365), I got the desired effect of hiding the selection highlight in a text input.

My use case of programmatically controlling selection involved the input element's `setSelectionRange` [(docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) and [listening for whenever the caret position changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755633/detect-when-cursor-position-inside-input-change-in-jquery).