# Span overflow when value set programmatically not typed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a span on top of an input field, basically to manipulate the styling of the input text ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v127c14p/11/)).

It works great as long as you don't type past the input box border, or this happens: [image]

Now, I learned that you could have the same scrolling effect as input for the span, like this:

```
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
```

But, since I am not typing in the span directly, but just updating the innerHTML, this has no effect.

Is there a way I can update the span, so it would treat the updates as typing?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not just styling the input text itself? Am i missing something here? =)

Comment: I wish that was possible, but you cannot change the color of only part of the text like that.. (or I dont know of a way)

Comment: Ahh... i see. you want like half the text one color and the other another... gotcha. hmmm... interesting.

Comment: What about using a paraghraph and content-editable?

Comment: Contenteditable was also one idea, but I didnt know that you could style only part of it with a paragraph if that's what you're implying

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simulate the same effect setting the `scrollLeft` really high property on the span as you type on it. You also need to explicitly set the same width on both the input and the span.

You can see a working [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/v127c14p/17/).

I make a "fake" span, hidden and with variable width, so I can use it to set the scrollLeft property to the width the text would have if it were to behave normally.

To handle the "cursor moving" events, I check the cursor position ([via @RenatoPrado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19803814/8469069)), and set `scrollLeft` to the percentage of the width of the text. So it's working almost like a real `input` field, but it's still not perfect. This only triggers on `keyup` (keydown was not working too well), so it has a "lag". And you can't see the blinking cursor, so that's annoying. But hopefully this sets you on the right track.

Comment: What is the property for the `scrollLeft`?

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: what does the `10000` stand for?

Comment: It's just a "real high" value, as to make sure the span scrolls to the rightmost part. Of course this is not ideal, but getting the width of the typed text is not trivial, I'm working on a more elegant solution as we speak.

Comment: I see, it works great as long as you just type, but yeah, as soon as you drag the text with the cursor it messes up

Comment: I fixed the `10000` issue by creating a fake span, setting the text to it as well and using it to measure the would-have-been width of the span. Working on the cursor thing now.

Comment: would just leaving it to `10000` cause any problems assuming it never reaches that point? Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't see how it should. However it's always nice to have more elegant solutions in your code, instead of those "hacky" ones.

Comment: OK so I got the cursor events working almost perfectly. I don't like the solution at all, still find it kinda buggy... but I hope it helps you. See the edit!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Do you by any chance have an Idea of how I could achieve what I want differently? (i.e. change color of only part of the input text)

Comment: Hah I got so immersed in this fun challenge I didn't even think of other options. Sadly, I think there's no "native" way of doing this, as the styling you apply to an `input` is applied to it as a whole. I'm sure someone has developed a jQuery plugin for this though.

Comment: Yeah, that's also what I figured... (BTW I think you forgot to update the fiddle)

Comment: I totally did. Updated now! Thanks!