# JS event for capturing spacebar swipe to move cursor in input

Tags: javascript, mobile, dom-events

For mobile devices, when you swipe the spacebar in an input field, the cursor changes position. What JS event is used to capture that event?

Comment: Have you tried anything? You are looking for something like this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755633/detect-when-cursor-position-inside-input-change-in-jquery

Comment: Tried mousedown, mousemove, etc. Can't seem to find the specific event in MDN's event reference.

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`selectionchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event) to detect changes of the caret/cursor:

```js
document.onselectionchange = () => {
    var sel = document.getSelection()
    info.innerHTML =
       'anchorOffset: ' + sel.anchorOffset + '<br>' +
       'focusOffset: ' + sel.focusOffset + '<br>'
}
```

```html
<p contenteditable>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua</p>

<div id="info">info</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xz1upsk8